# Creating new variable names within functions using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I want to be able to rename a variable based on an argument passed into a function using `dplyr::rename`. Here is the dataset.

```
set.seed(1)
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(group = rep(letters[2:4], each = 2), score = round(rnorm(6),2))
df

#   group score
# 1     b -0.63
# 2     b  0.18
# 3     c -0.84
# 4     c  1.60
# 5     d  0.33
# 6     d -0.82
```

I can rename the `score` variable in `dplyr` like so

```
df %>% dplyr::rename(score_7of9 = score)

#   group score_7of9
# 1     b      -0.63
# 2     b       0.18
# 3     c      -0.84
# 4     c       1.60
# 5     d       0.33
# 6     d      -0.82
```

Using base R I can also rename the variable by pasting a suffix to the named variable passed within a function

```
renameFunct <- function(data, suffix) {

colnames(data)[2] <- paste0("score", suffix)

return(data)
}

renameFunct(df, "_7of9")

#   group score_7of9
# 1     b      -0.63
# 2     b       0.18
# 3     c      -0.84
# 4     c       1.60
# 5     d       0.33
# 6     d      -0.82
```

However when I try to do a similar thing in the tidyverse...

```
renameFunct2 <- function(data, suffix) {
d <- data %>% dplyr::rename(paste0("score", !!suffix) = score)  
return(d)
}
```

...it simply doesn't work

Honestly I find writing functions using tidyverse verbs incredibly confusing, with all the `as.symbol()`, `quosure()` and `!!` functions. I have tried multiple combinations of these functions but can't get it to work. Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: Use `d <- data %>% dplyr::rename(!!paste0("score", suffix) := score) ` or `{{}}`.

Comment: Thank you @Ronak Shah. You came through as usual. The `:=` was the thing I needed.